# 2 цвета в ячейке таблицы html

Tags: html, css

Можно ли в одной ячейке сделать так, чтобы половина ячейки была одного цвета, а вторая половина - другого ?

Answer (score 2):

можно

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #000000;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #000000 50%, #0000ff 51%, #0000ff 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(50%, #000000), color-stop(51%, #0000ff), color-stop(100%, #0000ff));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #000000 50%, #0000ff 51%, #0000ff 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #000000 50%, #0000ff 51%, #0000ff 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #000000 50%, #0000ff 51%, #0000ff 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%, #000000 50%, #0000ff 51%, #0000ff 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#0000ff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А в какой тэг записывать table и td с фигурными скобками ?